# Center vertically UILabel text in table view section header

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How to change position of the text in tableview section? I use viewForHeaderInSection:Section and i create there somwthing like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Bold" size:17.0f];

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.comlpetedFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    label.text = [@" " stringByAppendingString:[sectionInfo name]];
    return label;
}
```

It doesnt matter what size is the parameters in UILabel frame, i always get the same result:

[image]

How can i center text in UILabel vertically?
Thanks

Comment: You can see that text is on the top of black UILabel, i want to make it center (a little bit down that now)

Comment: Did you try centering the text in the label using label. textAlignment  =UITextAlignmentCenter

Comment: did you try to change y? UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 3, 300, 30)];

Comment: @Simone yes i tried, nothing work.

Comment: ok, and if you create a UIView, and put the UILabel on it with y changed and return the UIView instead of UILabel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the label in a UIView then return the view:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];
[view addSubview:label];
return view;
```

Make sure you implement the following method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

otherwise your view will simply be on top of the cells.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
[yourLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[yourLabel sizeToFit];
[yourLabel setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
```

Answer (score 2):

Go through this link: [NSTextAlignment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTextAlignment)

Also code snippet given below, may help you

```
  UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

  [myLabel setText:@"Abc"];
  [myLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```